# How do I link to Django static assets from my JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to load a specific file but failing due to the way Django manages relative paths. Here's the structure of my app:

```
mysite
|-- manage.py
|-- mysite
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- settings.py
    |-- urls.py
    |-- wsgi.py
|-- app
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- models.py
    |-- tests.py
    |-- views.py
    |-- static
        |-- JS
            |-- myScript.js
        |-- data
            |-- myData.geojson
|-- templates
    |-- app
        |-- index.html
```

In other words, pretty standard. The two key parts are that I load myScript.js in to my index.html like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="{% static '/JS/myScript.js' %}"></script>
```

The issue is that, within myScript.js, I want to load in myData.geojson. This doesn't work:

```
...
'url': '/static/data/myData.geojson'
...
```

nor does

```
'url': '{% static /data/myData.geojson %}' #this throws an error
```

I just want a project setup where I can use relative path to do this:

```
'url': '../data/myData.geojson'
```

Is that possible? My current settings are this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/mysite/static'
```

Answer (score 0):

Django converts the `static` template tag URLs into its corresponding absolute URIs at render time. You cannot use Django template tags in your JavaScript files. There are two ways to get around this problem.

1. Find out the absolute URI of the resource, and use that in your JS file.
2. Move the section that requires the use of an external link into your HTML file. And do the following:

`<span id="absoluteURIResource" style="display: hidden;">{% static "path/to/your/resource" %}</span>`

and then in your JavaScript you can access this as:

`var path = document.getElementByID("absoluteURIResource").innerHTML;`

The second one is more of a hack, figuring out the absolute URI would be easier.